# insertBefore changes nested html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm making a text editor. And i have a contenteditable paragraph.

```
<p id="empty-line" class="nText selectedT" contenteditable="true">
<h2>User is typing here...</h2>
</p>
```

I'm changing `<div></div>` tags with `<br>` if user hits enter in contenteditable area. And i'm getting the html value of #empty-line in a variable.

```
var data = $('#empty-line').html().replace(/<div>/gi,'<br>').replace(/<\/div>/gi,'');
```

And i'm creating new paragraph with the data and inserting it before the #empty-line element.

```
$('<p class="line nText" contenteditable="true">' + data + '</p>').insertBefore($('#empty-line'));
```

But when i added that content in another paragraph the h2 tag goes out of p elements like this.

```
<p class="line nText" contenteditable="true"></p>
<h2>Try this text</h2>
```

I checked data variable with console.log there is no problem with it.

```
console.log('<p class="line nText" contenteditable="true">' + data + '</p>');
```

Is insertBefore works differently with nested html elements? Can you help to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you create an MCVE that demonstrates the problem? Use [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to embed it in the question.

Comment: Side note I believe you have a logic flaw in how you are constructing your new line.  You are creating the html and then letting jquery parse it into dom Elements, however the potential exists that a user could type </p> and mess that up, if I am not reading this incorrectly.  To fix that you could create your $('<p>') and append() or html() the data to it.

Comment: This seems a bit confusing - my instinct is that Headers are headers and Paragraphs are paragraphs. I wouldn't put a header inside a para - nor would I put a Div inside a header or para unless it was set to inline or inline-block. (But I would put a para inside a div, but not a header). When you try things like this, the browser will reset things to what it considers a more correct way of doing things.

Comment: I did a quick fiddle using the insertBefore logic like in the question.  As is, i replicated the issue.  using html(data) it put the h2 inside the p as expected.

Comment: @Taplar i'm clearing all html tags inside of contenteditable element which added by user. I'm adding that h tags by documentExec(). And i will try again and check all of my code. I don't know yet whats the reason of it.

Comment: @TonyDuffill you are right the hierarchy is not as expected. But for manipulating data easily i had to do like that. I'm displaying that content without changing (exactly the same) on the frontend which written in editor page.

Comment: Yes - PS: Just re-reading what I wrote: ' (But I would put a para inside a div, but not a header)' -- just to clarify, I meant a para inside a header - headers can go inside divs OK.